# How to include cron in bash script?

Tags: bash, cron

I want to write a script which will executes everyday. Can i include crontab in it or something else? I need it in one .sh file.

Comment: If you want a script that executes every day, you would write a normal script, then run `crontab -e` to add it as daily `cron` job. You wouldn't include `cron` within your script. Try a google search on "how to set up a cron job". Also see `man crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is a way to run commands at specified intervals. It is not a library that is included or invoked in scripts.

To do what you're trying to achieve write your script and then create a crontab to run your script daily.

An example resource on setting up a crontab: http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

An example cron entry to run things once a day at 6:30 PM from the above reference:

`30     18     *     *     *         rm /home/someuser/tmp/*`